# MaterializeCSS Select Box, How to get it to work with Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, materialize

I am using [MaterializeCss](http://materializecss.com/forms.html) and I am wondering how I get it's select box to work with reactjs

I have this

```
 <div className="input-field col m6 lg6">
                                    <select name="selectedUnitType" value={this.state.selectedUnitType}  onChange={ (event) => this.handleChange(event) }  >
                                        {
                                            this.props.unitTypes.map((unitTypes, i) => {
                                                return <option key={'unitTypes-' + i}  value={unitTypes.id}>{unitTypes.name}</option>;
                                            })
                                        }
                                    </select>
                                </div>
```

I then have these 2 functions

```
validate() {
    console.log(this.state);
}
handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
}
```

handleChange should change the state and validate would be executed on my "add" button and just logs right now the state so I can see if it changed.

However materializecss does some changing of the dom and in the end the html output looks like this

```
 <div class="select-wrapper initialized">
   <span class="caret">▼</span><input type="text" class="select-dropdown" readonly="true" data-activates="select-options-de36c20b-d50b-3b4b-2349-6d9f35e507f0" value="Meat">
   <ul id="select-options-de36c20b-d50b-3b4b-2349-6d9f35e507f0" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown ">
      <li class=""><span>Meat</span></li>
      <li class=""><span>Fruit</span></li>
   </ul>
   <select class="initialized">
      <option value="839751d4-7ed8-4aee-b439-12c7bfb47f43">Meat</option>
      <option value="6b31ef3e-ad80-40fa-899a-9523dd2260b4">Fruit</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

so I am not really sure how to do as now it's been changed to an unordered list

Answer (score 0):

Materialize will change your select input to UL and options to li.

Give a id to your div that encloses the select input and use it to trigger the text input value change event (jquery).

```
<div class="input-field col m6 lg6" id="selectUnitTypeDiv">
<div class="select-wrapper initialized">
<span class="caret">▼</span><input type="text" class="select-dropdown"    readonly="true" data-activates="select-options-de36c20b-d50b-3b4b-2349-6d9f35e507f0" value="Meat">
<ul id="select-options-de36c20b-d50b-3b4b-2349-6d9f35e507f0" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown ">
  <li class=""><span>Meat</span></li>
  <li class=""><span>Fruit</span></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Write the onchange event in componentDidMount of the element:

```
   componentDidMount(){
     $('#selectUnitTypeDiv .select-wrapper input[type=text]').change(function() {
           this.setState({ /*whatever the variable is*/ });
     });
   }
```